# Sort files by name as if they were dates

Tags: bash, directory, ls

I have a backup bash script which hashes everything into a tar.gz in a backup dir.
For a restore script, I need to be able to select the single newest one from bash.
the format of my backup folder is `backup/YYYY-MM-DD/HH-MM.tar.gz`

example file structure would be

```
/2016-03-08/1230.tar.gz
/2016-03-08/0615.tar.gz
/2016-03-07/0615.tar.gz
```

Comment: Would picking the file with the latest modification date work?

Comment: for deleting after x days? I guess, but then I have to enable that after x days. But first I need to have a quick restore-backup script

Comment: Also for selecting the newest one. I asked this to because for example `touch`ing one of the backup would affect its mtime, and it's not clear what these files are subjected to. Just to make sure that'd be fine.

Comment: it is fine by me, as long as the name doesn't change.

Comment: Do you mean `backup/YYYY-MM-DD/…`? You used the backslash, which is for Windows.

Comment: For deletion after x days, simply use `date`. E.g. 5 days ago = minus 5 days, thus `date -d-5days +%Y-%m-%d` in combination with your removal command. You could also use `date` in a loop to select the latest day, then the time via comparing the highest numbers. Also: have you considered using `backuppc`? It's quite simple, reliable, allows for recovery and no need for your own script (you lose some training, though...).

Comment: In general, but moreover since muru answered this already, too unrelated questions should be asked separately. I see that both of your questions are related to the same task, but perhaps the deletion of the backups after N days deserves a separate question.

Comment: but how would you parse them to a list of datetimes? that's my question

Comment: I'll edit that out kos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the filename and directory structure, you can probably just use `find` and `sort`:

```
find backup -type f -iname '*.tar.gz' | sort -r | head -1
```

This should return the newest file. Dates of the form `YYYY-MM-DD/HHMM` sorted lexicographically give a sorted order with respect to time as well.

To get this file in a variable, use command substitution:

```
newest_file=$(find backup -type f -iname '*.tar.gz' | sort -r | head -1)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Simple and elegant